# Declare let global misunderstanding with Prisma

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prisma

I'm trying to understand what this means --

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
declare let global: { prisma: PrismaClient };
```

In this example, is "global" a simple variable that's being pulled from "prisma," or is something else going on here?

I see no explanations for this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like TypeScript.

A `declare` line only tells the TypeScript compiler that a variable exists despite not being obviously initialized (like with a `const someVarName = someValue`).

`declare let` means that the variable is reassignable.

What comes after the `let` (or `const`) is the variable name. So `declare let global` tells TypeScript: "A reassignable variable named `global` exists in this current scope, despite no `let global =` appearing above."

It looks like `PrismaClient` is a type (and not a value) - from TypeScript, rather than from JavaScript. (For example, `type obj = { prop: string }` is another type.) The

```
: { prisma: PrismaClient }
```

means that the type of the `global` is an object, and that object has one property, `prisma`. That property's *shape* is that of `PrismaClient`, the type that was imported above.

Neither of the lines in your code actually result in any changes to the emitted JavaScript code - they just help the TypeScript compiler, and get removed when compiled into JavaScript.

---

For a similar example, one could write the following:

```
// Describe the shape of an object, put it into the MyLibrary type
type MyLibrary = { method: (arg: string) => boolean };
// Tell TypeScript that a variable named myLibrary exists and has the type above
declare let myLibrary: MyLibrary;

// Now you can use the `myLibrary` identifier
// and TypeScript won't complain about it not being recognized
console.log(myLibrary.method('foo'));
```